# A struct initialised in a function how can i use the values?

Tags: c, function, struct

i have a struct that is filled with data in a function. 
Now i wanna know how i can use this data with an other function.

what should i write in my main function?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct anzeige
{
char gesamtzahl_zeilen_sonne;
char sichtbare_zeilen_sonne;
char himmel[80];
char horizont[80];
char sonne[20][80];
char text_fuer_benutzer[200];
int sleep; // ms f�r Animation
} Anzeige;

Anzeige initialisiere_anzeige()
{
Anzeige a;
strcpy(a.himmel, " \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[0], "          o o              \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[1], "      o         o          \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[2], "    o    ()  ()   o        \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[3], "   o               o       \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[4], "   o        V      o       \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[5], "    o    <____>   o        \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[6], "      o         o          \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[7], "          o o              \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[8], "                           \n");
strcpy(a.sonne[9], "                           \n");
strcpy(a.horizont, "---------------------------\n\n");
a.gesamtzahl_zeilen_sonne = 10;
a.sichtbare_zeilen_sonne = 10;
strcpy(a.text_fuer_benutzer, "\'u\': Untergang\t \'a\':\n\nAuswahl: ");
a.sleep = 50;
return a;
}

void zeichnen(struct Anzeige a){

}

int main(){

zeichnen(struct Anzeige a);

return 0;
}
```

i want to print the sun with an extra function. (zeichnen)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do

```
int main(void) {
    struct anzeige a; // or Anzeige a; using the typedef
    a = initialisiere_anzeige();
    zeichnen(a);
    return 0;
}
```